# net cat client and server model

Tags: networking, netcat

I tried to make server client model  as below

on one shell
    `nc -l -p 8080` this works as a server
and on another
    `nc 127.0.0.1 8080` and this works as a client

all of this is fine ... the problem that  if I closed the client  the server closes also .. how can I keep server working after terminating client ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netcat` has a `-k` option that does what the OP wanted a year ago:

From [the man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc):

```
-k      Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its 
        current connection is completed. It is an error to use this option with‐
        out the -l option.
```

So this should work:

```
nc -lk -p 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
while :; do
    netcat -l -p 8080 
done
```

Comment: thnx alot it works ^____________^